# How to render an SVG without antialiasing in Qt/hook QPainter to avoid antialiasing?

Tags: c++, qt, svg, antialiasing

I need to render a vector-only SVG *without antialiasing* in Qt; specifically, I don't want the resulting image to contain any color that was not exactly as specified in the source file.

When loading an SVG in a `QImage`, Qt by default uses antialiasing; even using explicitly `QSvgRenderer::render`, the `QPainter::Antialiasing` render hint is ignored.

This turns out to be obvious, as `QSVGTinyDocument::draw`, which seems to be the one who actually starts the drawing, [is forcing it set](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtsvg.git/tree/src/svg/qsvgtinydocument.cpp?h=5.12#n248):

```
//sets default style on the painter
//### not the most optimal way
mapSourceToTarget(p, bounds);
QPen pen(Qt::NoBrush, 1, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::FlatCap, Qt::SvgMiterJoin);
pen.setMiterLimit(4);
p->setPen(pen);
p->setBrush(Qt::black);
p->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
p->setRenderHint(QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform);
```

To circumvent this I tried to create a custom `QPaintEngine` wrapping the default one (and then subclass even `QImage` to return the wrapper `QPaintEngine` in the `paintEngine()` virtual method), but I couldn't find any clean way to intercept and alter the render hint on the way to the actual `QPaintEngine`.

The `QPaintEngine::update()` method, which seems to be the way through which a `QPaintEngine` receives the flags, receives a reference to a `QPaintEngineState`, which is a horrible kludge that provides only getters, which in turn

- aren't `virtual`, so you cannot provide your implementation;
- internally just assumes it's actually operating an instance of an internal subclass (`QPainterState`) [by brutally casting the `this` pointer](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/gui/painting/qpainter.cpp#n8203) and accessing its fields.

Besides, even just providing a just-forwarding `QPaintEngine` resulted in segfaults inside the bowels of `QPainter` code, so I quickly desisted.

---

Long story short:

- is there a way to forcibly disable/intercept and ignore/... the `QPainter::Antialiasing` render hint on a `QPainter`? (the [`QT_NO_ANTIALIASING` environment variable](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/gui/painting/qpainter.cpp#n7136) doesn't count, as it is enabled only in builds without `QT_NO_DEBUG`);
- more in general, how can I render an SVG to a `QImage` *without* antialising?

Answer (score 1):

Not an optimal solution, but that may help you, is to remove the alpha-channel in a temporary image by the use of a mask, thus creating the *appearance* of an aliased rendering. The function below takes the `QImage` you are currently rendering antialiased and returns an aliased equivalent.

This workaround is probably impractical for real-time rendering, but if you only wish to create the `QImage`s in a pre-process step, it should make the work.

```
QImage convertToAliased(const QImage& source)
{
  const auto mask = QPixmap::fromImage(source.createAlphaMask());

  QImage image(source.size(), QImage::Format_ARGB32);
  image.fill(Qt::transparent);

  QPainter p;
  p.begin(&image);
  p.setClipRegion(QRegion(mask));
  p.drawImage(QPoint(0, 0), source.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_RGB32));
  p.end();

  return image;
}
```

Code can also be found [here](https://github.com/cbuchart/stackoverflow/tree/master/55301074-how-to-render-an-svg-without-antialiasing) in GitHub.

Comment: Antialiasing is not limited to the external borders, but is applied even to borders between internal, differently filled areas, where it "invents" new colors by blending them. This code will give an aliased _appearance_ on the outside border, but won't give me a real aliased image, made of just the colors that are explicitly specified in the SVG file.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I can think of is to implement your own SVG renderer. This is trivial using `nanosvg`, yet few people decide to do this. Also, like almost every other parser out there, `nanosvg` does not support every SVG feature (like filters, ...). Anyway, here's an [example](https://github.com/user1095108/qtnanosvg/). You will have complete control, whether you want (anti)aliasing or not.